# Set up Vim to work with R and Sweave in Windows

Tags: windows, r, vim, latex, sweave

I have installed vim in windows and would like to configure it so i can send code to R. I want to also use Sweave with it. However, i have Googled and failed to find clear step-by-step instructions on how to set this up.

my attempts so far:

1. installed Vim using executable from ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/pc/gvim73_46.exe
2. downloaded R-plugin from https://github.com/jcfaria/Vim-R-plugin/zipball/master and extracted it to a folder on my pc. following instructions in the r-plugin.txt file, i installed python-3.2.msi and pywin32-216.1.win32-py3.2exe. I extracted the  plugin zip-file to C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vimfiles\ merging like-named folders together.  then i opened Vim and typed :helptags C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vimfiles\doc. I closed Vim then I started R and reopened Vim. I typed :new anewfile.R and got the error message

> "Python interface must be enabled to run Vim-R-Plugin. Please do  ':h r-plugin-installation details

and when i type this i get

> error149, no help for r-plugin-installation

I also did not see the buttons that send code to R.

I failed to understand the instruction that , "You may have to
adjust the value of |vimrplugin_sleeptime|."

What should i do?
-I already have Miktex 2.9 on my PC. will Vim see it? How do I set up Vim to see Latex?
Will appreciate any help.

Note: I have used rstudio with Sweave and also eclipse but there are some issues i need to resolve and hence need to try vim and see how it will work out.

Comment: Don't know about VIM (never used it), but what are the issues in Eclipse?

Comment: in vim, :!R --vanilla < code.R not help ?

Comment: @Roman Luštrik  In eclipse/statet when i run texi2dvi() my error messages are suppressed and thus i cant tell when why or whether I have an an error. I have problems managing workspaces and projects. I cant create new projects of the same perspective in a folder where i have an existing project i a subfolder. When i delete metadata folder then i can but then i cant open the old project. In Rstudio i see the error messages but i get many errors related to encoding issues which i don't understand very well. also i cant compare my code files in the same window (say with tabs) due to lack of space

Comment: Regarding comparing code, did you mean something along the lines of http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8161901/eclipse.jpg ? Other error messages are probably related to somewhat faulty setting.

Comment: @Jirapong this sends the code and transfers control to the console until i close it meaning i can only source a file or type in the console. This doesn't give me the interaction i need. If you have used rstudio or eclipse/statet you will understand. I seem to have seen on the internet somewhere that Vim can be all that.

Comment: @Roman yes, this http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8161901/eclipse.jpg is what i meant

Comment: @Roman if i can figure out how to avoid suppressed errors in eclipse, and if i can find a way to help me manage my projects then i will be ok.

Comment: Here is the link to the blog where i got info about Vim's capabilities: http://www.r-bloggers.com/reasons-for-transitioning-to-vim-bringing-latex-r-sweave-and-more-under-one-roof/

Comment: You can't create projects within projects (I think you can link them, though). I create folders to accommodate my desired tree structure.

Comment: Can eclipse support code folding for Rnw?

Comment: It can close brackets and color syntax, but it's a step short of automatic folding (AFAICR, but would love to see be proven wrong).

Comment: I'm having this same problem with a fresh installation of the R plugin.  The old one on my desktop works fine; the new one I'm trying to put on my laptop is giving me the same errors.  I've tried with both Python 2.7 and 3.2.

Comment: Although I should note that I'm not having any problems with the `:h r-plugin-installation`.  It's just the message about the Python interface.

Comment: This isn't an answer, so I'll leave it here, but: I solved this by ritualistically uninstalling and reinstalling different components until it... just... worked.  Start by trying Python 2.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that this solution will not satisfying you completely but Rstudio IDE features a basic VIm editing mode: Global Option > Code Editing > Enable vim editing mode.

Answer (score 0):

I think the windows binaries of Vim 7.3 need Python 2.7 or 3.1. You can check the information that you get via `:version`; the linked Python version is somewhere in it.

So my solution would be installing Python 2.7 (+pywin32 for python 2.7). Also, check if Python is working in Vim before trying to use the R plugin.

Comment: I am also having the same problems as OP.  How do I check if Python is working in Vim?

Comment: @thequerist In vim try something like `:python print "Hello World"` or :python3 for Python 3.1. If python is working you will see a 'Hello World'; if not, you get an error msg (E370: Could not load ...)

Comment: Python is working fine.  I will have to reinstall the R plugin (to get the exact wording of the error messages) as I gave up all hope on it and removed it.